# Can I manually upgrade laptop CPU?

Tags: laptop, cpu, sony-vaio

I have an old Sony vaio laptop with Intel Core Duo T7500 and a dell with Intel core i5-6300hq. If I purchased Intel i7-6700K processor, can I manually remove the core i5 processor from the dell laptop and install the 6700k processor and then remove the T7500 processor from the Sony vaio laptop and replace it with the 6300hq processor?

If I did this, will everything boot up as normal or do I need to do additional things, like install drivers or whatever?

Comment: I haven't checked the models but you will have to check the manual very carefully. You probably won't be able to use a 6700k as it is a desktop model and it's pretty common that CPUs are soldered to the motherboard in notebooks.

Comment: You **cannot** replace a mobile CPU with a desktop CPU.

Answer (score 1):

In short: **NO**

In less short:

There are a few things that might prevent you from upgrading your laptop CPU:

1. The Intel Core Duo T7500 uses the PBGA479 socket, while the i7-6700K uses the LGA1151 socket. This means that the processors do not have the same 'connectors' on the bottom.
2. Laptop and Desktop processors are non interchangeable, so you'll need to somehow get a laptop i7-6700K. As far as I know, you can't just walk into a store and buy something like that.
3. Most laptop processors are welded to the motherboard. While you could be able to remove the old processor (I'm not too sure about recycling it in another computer), getting the new processor welded to the board will prove to be very challenging.

If you want to speed up your old laptop, getting some more RAM or investing in an SSD is often enough to boost your laptop for a bit. I usually notice the most performance improvements by doing a clean Windows (or Linux, I don't judge) install on an SSD. You won't be able to run most current high-end applications with ease, though. For that you'll need to upgrade your entire laptop.